# How to add list of email id in recipientlist in jenkins using python?

Tags: python, email, jenkins

I have one python script which i am running from jenkins.
After performing some other tasks this python script extracts email ids from another file and appends in a list.
Now i need to add this list of email ids in recipient list of "Editable Email Notificaiton" in jenkins without stopping the build.

Please tell me how can i add recipients as mentioned above?

I tried changing config.xml file of my job. But without refreshing Jenkins, changes done in config file does not reflect in Jenkins GUI.
I cannot refresh Jenkins as i need to run python script and then send email notification to selected developers in one job only.

Comment: Ho about write the recipient list into a file and use the plugin ```Inject environment variables``` to change the variable ```$DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS```?

Comment: yeah i was trying with Inject environment variables only and it worked. Thanks :)